Flutter Error: Build failed with an exception
I have a simple Flutter App that uses the Flutter Package "device_info_plus".
I am using a MacBook Pro M1 with Visual Studio Code.
I have an Android Smartphone with Android 13. So i want to run the app on this phone.
I am getting the following error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':device_info_plus:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


error: invalid source release: 17


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Does anyone have an idea what i can do to fix this error?
If i create a Simple Hello World Flutter App i can run this without any errors on the Android Phone.
I tried different Android Smartphones with different Android Versions. But everywhere the same error.

Which version of device_info_plus you're using?

I am using device_info_plus: ^10.1.0

And what about java version? you can use this java --version

Apparently none at all. I did this for my environment https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos/mobile-ios?tab=vscode so there is no notification to install java. I'm confused.

Please check my answer and also this https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos/mobile-android?tab=vscode, the config you sent was for iOS, and the error you posted is and android issue

I faced the same error weeks ago, I did the next steps

Use java 17 to compile, you can check your config with: java --version and the output should be something similar to this:


Update android studio to the latest version, right now the latest is


Force the version of plus packages like these:


  device_info_plus: 10.0.1
  package_info_plus: 5.0.1
  share_plus: 7.2.2


So in addition to Visual Studio Code, I also need Android Studio even though the Flutter application is created in Visual Studio etc. ?

Yep, since your building an android app you need to install android studio

I am building a Flutter App so its Cross Platform i thought. I can run it on Iphone or Android Phone. But ok for iPhone i need Xcode. So ok yes it makes then sense to get android studio for android.
